# Java: is there any other efficient way to do this

Tags: java

Input:--> I have different group name like:

> (gis06352.b.com ,corp.abcd.b.com ,corp.def.nam.b.com ,abc)

Required Output:

> (why_gis06352_not, why_abcd_not, why_def_not, why_abc_not)

CODE:

```
package a;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Group name : "
            + getgroupName("abc.logon.ds.b.com"));
}

public static String getTestGrpName(String groupName) {

    int idxOf;
    int idxOfLstDot;
    if (groupName != null && !"".equals(groupName)) {
        if (groupName.contains(".nam.corp.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".nam.corp.b.com");
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            groupName = "Why"
                    + groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";

        } else if (groupName.contains(".corporate.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".corporate.b.com");
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            groupName = "Why"
                    + groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";

        } else if (groupName.contains(".gis.corp.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".gis.corp.b.com");
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            groupName = "Why"
                    + groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";

        } else if (groupName.contains(".logon.ds.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".logon.ds.b.com");
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            groupName = "Why"
                    + groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";

        } else if (groupName.contains("copr1.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf("copr1.b.com");
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            groupName = "Why"
                    + groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";

        } else if (groupName.contains(".nam.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".nam.b.com");
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            groupName = "Why"
                    + groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";

        } else if (groupName.contains(".b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".b.com");
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            groupName = "Why"
                    + groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";
        }

        else {
            groupName = "Why" + groupName + "Not";
        }
    }
    return groupName;
}
}
```

Output:

> why_abc_not

Comment: How do you know which part of the group name you want? You seem to have just hardcoded values for the examples you've got.

Comment: yes, I have set of group names which is categorized as below :
Remove suffix from GRP name like-->

.nam.corp.b.com
.corporate.b.com
.gis.corp.b.com
.b.com
.nam.b.com
.copr1.b.com
.logon.ds.b.com

before this first dot we need to add WHy_ & NOT_ at front and end rspctvly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temp variable and combine the common line based on that temp variable.

temp=true;

```
if (groupName != null && !"".equals(groupName)) {
        if (groupName.contains(".nam.corp.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".nam.corp.b.com");

        } else if (groupName.contains(".corporate.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".corporate.b.com");


        } else if (groupName.contains(".gis.corp.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".gis.corp.b.com");

        } else if (groupName.contains(".logon.ds.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".logon.ds.b.com");


        } else if (groupName.contains("copr1.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf("copr1.b.com");

        } else if (groupName.contains(".nam.b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".nam.b.com");

        } else if (groupName.contains(".b.com")) {
            idxOf = groupName.indexOf(".b.com");

        }
        else {
            groupName = "Why" + groupName + "Not";
            temp=false;
        }
        if(temp=true){
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            groupName = "Why"+ groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";
        }
    }
    return groupName;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My taste would be for the following. Modify to yours. :-)

```
private static final String[] knownGroupNames = { ".nam.corp.b.com", ".corporate.b.com", ".gis.corp.b.com",
        ".logon.ds.b.com", "copr1.b.com", ".nam.b.com", ".b.com" };

public static String getTestGrpName(String groupName) {
    if (groupName == null || groupName.isEmpty()) {
        return groupName;
    }
    for (String knownGroupName : knownGroupNames) {
        if (groupName.contains(knownGroupName)) {
            int idxOf = groupName.indexOf(knownGroupName);
            groupName = groupName.substring(0, idxOf);
            int idxOfLstDot = groupName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1;
            return "Why" + groupName.substring(idxOfLstDot) + "Not";
        }
    }
    return "Why" + groupName + "Not";
}
```

Comment: What in case if we have grp name like=(only abc) no dot?? as per ur code the output will come =abc and not (required output come which is) why_abc_not

Comment: Ah, I missed that case, sorry. I have edited and corrected.